# Passing parent component data to child via routerLink

Tags: angular

I have a parent component that has a this button in the html template:

```
<button class="button" [routerLink]="['/modify-alias-detail']">Next</button>
```

The above seems to work as I get the `edit-alias-detail works!` output.
But I'd like to pass some data from the parent to the child component so I tried this:

```
<button class="button" [routerLink]="['/modify-alias-detail', aliasName.value]">Next</button>
```

I get this error in the developer console:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'modify-alias-detail//'
```

I haven't used routerLinks before and I am rather new to angular 2.

Any help is appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to pass this value in the url? something like `/modify-alias-detail/1234` ?

Comment: Ah thank you! I should have been doing this instead: `<button class="button" [routerLink]="['/modify-alias-detail', aliasName]">Next</button>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in such way of navigation you can pass queryParams

```
<button class="button" (click)="goToAliasDetails(aliasName.value)">Next</button>
```

then in .ts

```
goToAliasDetails(aliasName: string) {
    this.router.navigate(['/modify-alias-detail'], {queryParams: {aliasName}});
}
```

but at the end your url will look like: /modify-alias-detail?aliasName=....